# if statement multiple conditions and brackets

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm fairly new to php. I was wondering how to make the statement below to check for the post meta equaling C1 or C2

```
if ( $user_ID && $user_ID == $convert->post_author && get_post_meta( $project->ID,'et_payment_package', true) == 'C1')
```

This doesn't seem to work

```
if ( ($user_ID && $user_ID == $convert->post_author && get_post_meta( $project->ID,'et_payment_package', true) == 'C1') || ($user_ID && $user_ID == $convert->post_author && get_post_meta( $project->ID,'et_payment_package', true) == 'C2') )
```

Comment: remove the first `$user_ID`

Comment: I'm not sure what removing the first $user_ID is going to do... I've checked the syntax and it should work fine. Check my answer below

Comment: @giollianosulit its superfluous; as user $user_ID has to equal some var, checking its 'truthy'  adds nothing

Comment: @nogad -  That makes sense, then I guess having a !empty check is a better option here

Comment: `$user_ID == $convert->post_author` takes care of that as well

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and cleanest way to do the checks is to split up the if statements. You don't need to do the whole check in one if statement:

```
// Check if $user_ID exists and it equals $convert->post author
if (!empty($user_ID) && $user_ID == $convert->post_author) {
    if (get_post_meta($project->ID, 'et_payment_package', true) == 'C1') {
        // run logic for C1
    }
    elseif (get_post_meta($project->ID, 'et_payment_package', true) == 'C2') {
        // run logic for C2
    }
}
```